# Query Corrupt Ms Access

Tags: excel, vba

I'm facing an issue while using excel user form to update any data into an access database.

Error: 'Query '' is corrupted'

Excel file is saved on a shared drive where multiple users can work as it is shared. I'm able to perform the update query but other users are getting the above error.

My SQL query to update the record is:

```
connection.execute sqlstatement
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: perhaps this is related to your issue? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/access-error-query-is-corrupt-fad205a5-9fd4-49f1-be83-f21636caedec

Answer (score 0):

> Depending on the version of Access you have installed, there are 4 updates that may be causing this issue:
>
> - Access 2010 – Uninstall update KB4484127
> - Access 2013 – Uninstall update KB4484119
> - Access 2016+ – Uninstall update KB4484113
> - Access 2016+ – Uninstall update KB3085368
>
> After uninstalling these updates, be sure that you then disable automatic updates or else Windows will simply reinstall it and you’ll be right back where you started.

https://www.devhut.net/2019/11/14/access-bug-error-3340-query-is-corrupt/

Comment: Is there any other process where we can overwrite these updates as I don't have permission to unistall any update or disable the automatic updates

Comment: Read the paragraphs after the table in the link I posted on my first comment, maybe that will help. If not try to install the 2007 version of access (apparently some people are doing that while waiting for the Microsoft's fix) and work there or in the worst-case scenario you'll have to wait for the fix that is estimated to be released in November 22 (if not, don't expect anything sooner than December)

Answer (score 0):

Do a Compact and Repair on Access.  Sometimes it fixes these kinds of issues.  As for Excel, open a new instance of Excel, click File > Open > navigate to the corrupt file > select the corrupt file > click the down arrow on the 'Open' button > click 'Open and Repair'.  Hopefully you and your team are back in business soon!!

Comment: I get it done by creating a new query as explained in above link. Thanks